# How to remove last character from a line only if it's a number in R or Linux

Tags: awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a list of ~28,000 gene transcripts, e.g.:

```
4R79.1b 
4R79.2b 
AC3.1a 
AC3.2 
AC3.3 
AC3.5a
```

I need to get gene names by removing the last character only if it's a letter. I've been googling for days and haven't found a solution that would remotely help, I must have missed something.

I thought there must be a simple solution but my best attempt was `sed 's/[[:alpha:]]$//' transcripts.txt > genes.txt` but it did not seem to do anything and the size of the file has not changed from the original.

Comment: So your example would become `4R79.1 4R79.2 AC3.1 AC3.2 AC3.3 AC3.5`?

Comment: You probably have DOS line endings and so every line ends with a CR, not a letter. See [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
$ echo '4R79.1b 4R79.2b AC3.1a AC3.2 AC3.3 AC3.5a' | 
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/[[:alpha:]]$/,"",$i)} 1'
```

Prints:

```
4R79.1 4R79.2 AC3.1 AC3.2 AC3.3 AC3.5
```

Or sed:

```
sed -E 's/[[:alpha:]]([[:space:]]|$)/\1/g'
```

For a new file, just redirect:

```
sed -E 's/[[:alpha:]]([[:space:]]|$)/\1/g' file > new_file
```

If you want to replace *inplace* you can use sed:

```
sed -i bak -E 's/[[:alpha:]]([[:space:]]|$)/\1/g' file
```

Or awk by redirecting to a new temp file then overwriting the original (which is what `sed -i` is doing...):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/[[:alpha:]]$/,"",$i)} 1' file > TEMP_FILE && mv -f TEMP_FILE file
```

You can also use GNU awk which has an inplace option as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot to mention that I only showed part of the transcript file as an example, I have 28,000 transcript names in total. Is there a solution without having to echo them all?

Comment: Just redirect to a new file or use `sed` for inplace replacement.

Comment: If you are going to remove possible white space from the end of lines proceeded by an alpha character you might as well remove white space from all lines too i.e. `sed 's/[[:alpha:]]\?[[:space:]]*$//' file`

Comment: @potong: Yes, great suggestion. The *original* post had all the targets on one line vs each target on its own line. Your suggestion makes perfect sense for items alone on a line (to trim trailing spaces if any) but would not work in the first case...